# How to overlay an image with a polygon shape in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, plot, polygon, shapefile

I have a 2D matrix of the surface albedo of a glacier, which I plot using imagesc:

```
figure,
imAlpha=ones(size(albedo));
imAlpha(isnan(albedo))=0;
imagesc(x,y,albedo,'AlphaData',imAlpha);
h = colorbar;
ylabel(h, 'Surface albedo \alpha (-)')
set(gca,'Ydir','normal');
set(gca,'color','w');
title('Surface albedo \alpha')
xlabel('X coordinate (m)')
ylabel('Y coordinate (m)');
set(gca,'FontSize',14);
set(gcf,'color','w');
```

I also have a shapefile of the outline of that glacier, which I read in as a polygon. I can plot it by using:

```
outline = shaperead('Glacier_outline_2020_2D.shp');
mapshow(outline)
```

How can I plot the outline of that shapefile polygon on top of the imagesc? In the end I want the polygon area to be transparant and the outline of the glacier on top of the imagesc. Can this be done in Matlab?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't have that toolbox, so I can't really check. Nonetheless, you should be able to do what you want by passing a [symbolazion rules structure](https://it.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/makesymbolspec.html). As an example, I guess you can set the `FaceAlpha` to 0 to make the polygon transparent.

Comment: You can see the similar examples in the web page https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/mapshow.html